# Django и модели только для тестов

Tags: django, юнит-тесты, миграция

Возникла необходимость в написании тестов для собственной ModelForm, но чтобы ее протестить нужны 2 модели

Как написать тест и создать 2 модели в Django в тестовой базе, не создавая их в боевой базе?

Django 1.11.X

---

UPDATE:

Не объекты модели, а сами модели, таблицы. при `./manage.py migrate` описанные модели (из таблицы) создаются в боевой базе. при './migrate test`они создаются в тестовой, той же командой`migrate`. Как сделать, чтобы таблицы создавались только в тестовой базе ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

В общем побродив на просторах интернета набрел на https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/7835, где как раз просят добавить в django этот функционал и приводят обходные пути.

Так же добавил новое приложение только с тестами, которое подключется только в тестовой окружении. Т.о. его модели появляются только в тестах, и не создаются в боевой базе.

Для удобства и уменьшения числа папок в проекте переместил приложение с тестами в папку tests основного приложения.

Answer (score 0):

Если вы используете встроенный, в дажнгу инструмент тестирования, то для прогонки тестов джанга создаёт отдельную базу, которую удаляет по завершению тестов. Поэтому боевая бд остаётся нетронутой.

Есть такая штука, называется модульные тесты. 
В питоне это класс `TestCase`

В джанге же, есть свой фреймворк, который использует уже питоновские модульные тесты.

from django.test import TestCase

MyTestClass(TestCase):

```
def setUp(self):
    # В этом методе можно создать предварительные данные
    # для использования их в тестах этого класса.
    # они будут удаляться по завершению каждого теста
    # и создаваться в начале каждого нового.
    MyClass.objects.create()

def test_my_test(self):
    # Здесь код самого теста
    pass
```

Документация по фреймворку unittest: https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html

Документация по расширению этого фреймворка для джанги: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/testing/overview/

Comment: Не является ответом. Для вопроизведения проблемы, напишите модель, которая создается в тестовой базе, но не создается в боевой.

Comment: @Za Ars, это у вас проблема не воспроизведена. Джанга автоматом создаёт тестовую бд, и если она её не создаёт, то значит вы не использовали для тестирования средства джанги.

Comment: @Za Ars, какой вопрос, такой и ответ.

Comment: @МистерФикс >Как написать тест и создать 2 модели в Django в тестовой базе, не создавая их в боевой базе?

Comment: @Za Ars, вы читали что я писал? Они итак там не будут создаваться. Но я понял, что вам нужно. Сейчас добавлю в ответ.

Comment: Не объекты модели, а сами модели, таблицы. при `./manage.py migrate` описанные модели (из таблицы) создаются в боевой базе. при './migrate test` они создаются в тестовой, той же командой `migrate`. Как сделать, чтобы таблицы создавались только в тестовой базе ?

Comment: @Za Ars, интересно, а как могут создаваться записи в бд, если в бд нет таблиц? Никак. Естественно, что создавая тестовую бд джанга создаёт и таблицы.

Comment: так как уже было сказано ранее несколько раз, нужно чтобы модели не обрабатывались в боевой базе и там не было их таблиц

Comment: @Za Ars, странные у вас методы. Копайте тогда в сторону использования нескольких баз данных в проекте.

Comment: Да не такие уж и странные. просто нужно оттестировать сложную форму для 2+ моделей с сохранением/позрузкой значений по связям

Comment: @Za Ars, ну да, только инструменты для этого предназначенные вас не устраивают, и хочется своих костылей каких-то. Ну делайте.

Comment: Да не сработуют стандартные инструменты, предложенные вами